# How do I set up the python/c library correctly?

Tags: python, c

I have been trying to get the python/c library to like my mingW compiler. The python online doncumentation; http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html#include-files only mentions that I need to import the python.h file. I grabbed it from the installation directory (as is required on the windows platform), and tested it by compiling the script:
    `#include "Python.h"`. This compiled fine. Next, I tried out the snippet of code shown a bit lower on the python/c API page:

```
PyObject *t;
t = PyTuple_New(3);
PyTuple_SetItem(t, 0, PyInt_FromLong(1L));
PyTuple_SetItem(t, 1, PyInt_FromLong(2L));
PyTuple_SetItem(t, 2, PyString_FromString("three"));
```

For some reason, the compiler would compile the code if I'd remove the last 4 lines (so that only the pyObject variable definition would be left), yet calling the actual constructor of the tuple returned errors.

I am probably missing something completely obvious here, given I am very new to C, but does anyone know what it is?

Comment: "undefined reference to <function name>", where each call to a python function gave the same error.

Comment: could it make a difference that my compiler is MingW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some crafty Googling, and if you are getting errors at the linker stage (the error messages might have hex strings or references to `ld`), you may need to make sure the Python library that ships with the Windows version has been converted to a format that GCC (MinGW) can read; see [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/06/28/compiling-python-extensions-with-distutils-and-mingw/), among other sites. Also ensure that GCC can find and is using the library file if needs be, using `-L/my/directory` and `-lpython26` (substituting appropriately for your path and Python version).

If the errors are at the compilation stage (if line numbers are given in the messages), make sure that you don't need to add any other directories to the include search path. Python might (I've not used its C API) include other header files in `Python.h` which are stored in some other directory. If this is the case, use the `-I/my/directory/` flag to GCC to tell it to search there as well.

Exact (copied-and-pasted) error messages would help, though.

---

***Warning***: The text below does not answer the question!

Did you put the code inside a function? Try putting it in `main`, like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PyObject *t;
    t = PyTuple_New(3);
    PyTuple_SetItem(t, 0, PyInt_FromLong(1L));
    PyTuple_SetItem(t, 1, PyInt_FromLong(2L));
    PyTuple_SetItem(t, 2, PyString_FromString("three"));

    return 0;
}
```

This code will be run on execution of the program. You can then use whatever other methods are provided to examine the contents of the tuple. If it isn't to be run separately as an executable program, then stick it in a differently-named method; I assume you have another way to invoke the function.

The `PyObject *t;` definition is valid outside the function as a global variable definition, as well as inside a function, declaring it as a local variable. The other four lines are function calls, which must be inside another function.

The above code on its own does not a program make. Are you trying to write a C extension to Python? If so, look at some more complete documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html).

Comment: yes, I put it inside the main function. I have come that far in C :) I forgot to paste it with the other code

Comment: @Bartvbl: Just checking! As I have asked in my edit (unfortunately timed, it seems :D), what is the intent behind the code? Why are you using the Python API?

Comment: Mainly to try out the library, but in the end I am hoping to port some openGL rendering code I have to C, where python remains the code generating the scene, and C basically pushes the geometry data forward to the GPU. Given that I still have a lot to learn about C on the way, I thought it would be a nice place to start here.

Comment: I've edited this to add further detail. If this still doesn't solve the problem, let me know.

Comment: woops.. I didn't notice your edit until I added mine. You basically ended up with the same result as me =) Thanks a lot for the effort! I appreciate that! One small note on the side: (on the windows platform) you need to copy the python library from the python root directory to the mingw directory. You can find the libpython26.a file in the "libs" directory in the python root. Then copy it to the lib directory in the mingw root.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some progress since I asked my question, and I thought I would just share it in case someone else is having similar problems.

These were the errors I got:

```
In function `main':
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_FromLong'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_FromLong'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
```

The errors I got were the result of missing libraries from the mingW compiler. So only including the header file in the source ode is not enough, there is also a special file required (.lib, .o, .a, ..) that needs to be included for compilation. It is possible to use the -l[path] flag on the mingW command line, but I found that codeBlocks ( http://www.codeblocks.org/ ) is the most convenient to use here. After creating a project, and going to Project>Build options.., you can specify the location of the library file under the linker settings tab. When you are done, build the project, and it will hopefully work.

I hope anyone struggling with similar problems have help from this :)